# Node: TypeError: (0 , util_1.promisify) is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm building a React web app with a Node / MongoDB back end. I'm very much a beginner.

I get the below error when running my app:

```
(0 , util_1.promisify) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , util_1.promisify) is not a function
    at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/sessions.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58420:50)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111824:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111247:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111481:21)
    at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46814:20)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111824:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111247:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111481:21)
    at ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/aggregation_cursor.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47531:27)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111824:31)
```

I've read various posts with the same error but I can't understand how I fix it in my code as it appears the error is coming from the base code for the MongoDB connection?